# What is the word class of 'third' here?

Tags: parts-of-speech, fused-head-constructions

What is the word class of *third* in the following sentence?

> When two dogs fight over a bone the third carries it away.

Is it a pronoun (because it replaces *dog*) or an adjective describing the third dog?

Comment: @elstiv You need to change "the" to "a".

Comment: @BillJ This sounds like a proverb; the "the" is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

John Lawler wrote an answer in a comment (my emphasis):

> **In this case it's being used as a (pro)noun** because *one* does not appear, but normally it's not a pronoun. Technically it's an ordinal number, and those are Quantifiers -- that's one of the new silicone parts of speech that they didn't tell you about in grammar school, but they come in handy nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

> *When two dogs fight over a bone* [*a third*] *carries it away.*

Ordinal numeral words are adjectives when they occur as dependents to a noun, as in "a second chance" / "a third person".

There's no noun in your example, though we *understand* "a third" to mean "a third dog".

Grammatically, "a third" is analysed as a fused modifier-head noun phrase. The fusion involves the modifier and the head of the NP, i.e. the adjective serves as modifier and head at the same time.